# Help connecting pendant light

Tags: electrical, light-fixture

[image]

I need help attaching these two wires. Do I just connect black and white? And then to black?

Comment: Was there a metal box there when you took the old fixture down? Or was there not an old fixture there to begin with?

Comment: There was no metal box. There was an old fixture beforehand but the wires were both connected to the black wire only.

Answer (score 1):

If the black wire with the label is connected to that black wire with the orange wire nut, remove that wire with the label. Then you'll need to install a ceiling plate similar to the one below and route the wires through it before installing the fixture. Connect the two fixture wires to the two black wires from the ceiling. You will want to turn off the power before doing any work.

[image]

Comment: Wow, thank you so much for your kindness and help